# procedure which does string comparison in mysql

Tags: mysql

My requirement is some thing like this. If I want to search a string "Bangalore" in the table. But the in the table their are some leading spaces and trailing spaces before and after the string. How to write a procedure which helps me to search the string in mysql. I want to search the string during the procedure call

Comment: *My requirement is* - should be close.. what you have tried?

Comment: You have to check TRIM() function ion MYSQL. Use this link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_trim

Answer (score 0):

Use pattern matching? I.e. where value like "%bangalore%"

This should suffice to retrieve the data as is, but I would highly recommend trimming the whitespace out of the data, as suggested above.